# Как происходит импорт классов из dll

Tags: c#, dll, clr

Представим, что есть некоторая библиотека классов .dll написанная на C#, в которой есть 100500 классов и столько же методов/полей в каждом и весит она вообще космические цифры. Представим, что есть вторая программа - консольное приложение C#, которое хочет использовать эту dll. dll подключается в проект просто через ссылку. Дальше представим, что в этом приложении есть следующий код:

```
TestClass a = new TestClass();
Console.WriteLine(a.add(10, 10));
Console.WriteLine(a.sub(20, 15));
```

Где `TestClass` - класс из dll.

Вопрос: как произойдет импорт из длл? При запуске процесса он возьмет и загрузит всю эту огромную библиотеку мне в процесс? Или же будет подгружать только используемые мной классы? Или же вообще будет подгружать только нужные методы?

Comment: Всю либу целиком - точно не загрузит. По методам - не в курсе.

Comment: Подозреваю, что либа на диске будет просто мэпиться на память процесса. При доступе к еще не подгруженной странице она считается с диска (только нужная страница, не весь файл).

Comment: Если судить по счетчикам из группы .NET CLR Loading (Total Classes Loaded, Bytes in Loader Heap), то классы грузятся по мере необходимости. Проверил на EF (либа 5 Мб), после инициализации DbContext в хипе лоадера только ~1Мб, а классов 250 (всего в EF более 3000 классов).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DLL из .NET может содержать несколько видов данных, в частности байт код (IL), метаданные, описывающие типы, метаданные, описывающие сборку и просто какие-то ресурсы, например, иконки.

При использовании библиотеки из неё будут загружены метаданные и байт код. С процессами в CLR всё несколько сложнее, чем в обычном Windows, поскольку там используется концепция *управляемого кода*, поэтому DLL загружаются не в ваш процесс, а в процесс приложения-хоста.

Но в целях упрощения можно считать, что да, в ваш процесс будет загружен весь код из DLL. По поводу его *огромности* есть сомнения — сейчас посмотрел наш проект, в котором 55 сборок, средний размер сборки 240 килобайт. Для современных компьютеров, где 4-8Гб ОЗУ сейчас уже вполне норма на обычных офисных машинах это копейки.

Если же вы видите действительно огромную DLL, которая «весит» 10 мегабайт, то скорее всего, в ней находится не только код, но и ресурсы, и они занимают большую часть файла. Вы можете проверить это предположение с помощью программы ILDASM, которая входит в состав .NET и позволяет посмотреть, из чего состоит сборка.

Ресурсы подгружаются только по мере надобности, хотя Windows в условиях избытка памяти может загрузить и всё сразу.

Comment: Длл таких размеров я не находил, я просто предположил. Но ведь в любом случае не круто, когда я использую из длл всего 1 класс, а загружаются в память все 100 классов? Это какая то растрата ресурсов получается, неужели в .NET это никак не оптимизировано?

Comment: @user218772 а вы не делайте такие библиотеки, в которых ничего не используете :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, вы правы, но все равно же, пусть даже в библиотека 2 маленьких класса, а используется только 1, но ведь все равно же не приятно осознавать, что 100 байт памяти занимает код, который вообще ничего вам не дает, ну а писать длл в которых всего 1 класс - это, по моему, тоже не вариант :)

Comment: @user218772 Дональд Кнут со свойственной ему иронией когда-то сказал, что корнем все зол является преждевременная оптимизация. Посмотрите [динамику цены одного мегабайта ОЗУ](http://www.jcmit.com/memoryprice.htm), сейчас она составляет 0,35 цента. Треть цента за мегабайт и каждые 2 года по закону Мура она снижается в 2 раза. В существующем решении кардинально выше скорость загрузки, потому что если вам нужны 50 классов из 100, вы обратитесь к диску 50 раз за каждым классом, а это действительно очень медленно. Поэтому при определении крутизны учитывайте приоритеты.

Comment: @user218772 Чтобы был яснее порядок цифр — при цене 35 сотых цента за мегабайт 100 потеряных байт стоят 35 миллионых цента или по существующему курсу, если я ничего не напутал при расчётах в голове — две тысячных копейки.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko, я не понимаю... какой смысл тогда вообще в длл в .NET? Не проще ли тогда будет просто поместить весь код в 1 экзэшник, а не разносить по либам, которые нужно постоянно таскать за экзэшником?

Comment: @user218772 Вы пишите так, как будто смысл DLL в оптимизации, но это не так. Понятие *модулей*, *библиотек* и так далее возникло на стыке 60-х и 70-х годов поскольку размер проектов стал слишком велик для удобной с ними работы, количество ошибок стало слишком большим. В начале 90-х был достигнут ещё один количественный скачок, и появились такие понятия, как *уровень* или *звено*. Приложение разбивают на *уровни* и *модули* для того, чтобы над ним проще было работать, в том числе командой и несколькими командами. Именно в этом смысл модулей, не в экономии миллионных долей цента на ОЗУ.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko. ладно, все раскидали, все объяснили, все понял) спасибо большое)